# How can I count and list the number of times a grouped value appears within that same group?

Tags: r, grouping, summarization

I have a data frame that I have grouped and then summarised by numerous fields:

```
gn %>% 
  group_by(`_source.time`) %>%
  summarize(
    leads_TRUE = sum(`_source.lead` == TRUE),
    leads_FALSE = sum(`_source.lead` == FALSE),
    leads_T_conv = sum(leads_TRUE) / nrow(gn),
    leads_F_conv = sum(leads_FALSE) / nrow(gn),
    overall_conv = sum(leads_T_conv + leads_F_conv) / 2
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

This gives me:

```
# A tibble: 64 x 6
   `_source.time` leads_TRUE leads_FALSE leads_T_conv leads_F_conv overall_conv
   <date>              <int>       <int>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
 1 2018-05-14              8          89      0.00161      0.0179        0.0587
 2 2018-05-15             31          68      0.00623      0.0137        0.0587
 3 2018-05-16             28          85      0.00563      0.0171        0.0587
```

How can I count the number of individual dates that occur (`_source.time`) and list them as a column (`date_count`)?

The output that I am looking for would be the same as

```
> gn$`_source.time` %>% table %>% as.matrix
           [,1]
2018-05-14   97
2018-05-15   99
2018-05-16  113
```

so that each date will have a count of how many times it occurs within the grouped data frame.

Comment: Couldn't you just add a `%>% mutate(date_count = leads_TRUE + leads_FALSE)` add the end of your chain?

Comment: That works but I need it to appear first and as both `leads_TRUE` and `leads_FALSE` appear after where I want the column to appear, it doesn't work for me. I know that I can reorder the columns manually, but is there another way to get it in the right place on the fly?

Comment: Does this work for you `%>% add_column(.data = ., date_count = .$leads_TRUE + .$leads_FALSE, .before = 2)` ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use `n()`?  That's a function built into summarize.   But getting the number of dates is a different question, it's not going to work with grouped data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `n_distinct`:

```
iris %>% group_by(round(Sepal.Length)) %>% summarize(n=n_distinct(Species))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#   `round(Sepal.Length)`     n
#                   <dbl> <int>
# 1                     4     1
# 2                     5     3
# 3                     6     3
# 4                     7     2
# 5                     8     1
```